# nginx randomly "times out" when accessed via public IP

Tags: networking, router, firewall, nginx, ip-address

I'm hoping somebody can point me toward a way to diagnose my problem. A tool or logs that can help find the issue. I think it's a networking problem. It doesn't seem related to the nginx configuration to me but more like issues with my router or network settings or something that's causing my public IP to time out with nginx.

When I access my nginx website by public ip, eg http://172.123.123.123, it works perfectly at first. However, if I refresh the page over the next few minutes then chrome will stop loading the page and sit there waiting for a response from the server for 40-50 seconds before showing it again. Sometimes it takes long enough for chrome to throw me the "site can't be reached" message. But, if I'm accessing my server via the local ip, http://192.168.1.x, it never has any issues. Also.. even while the server is taking those 40-50 seconds and not responding to the http request via public ip, I can still access my site by local ip without a hitch. I've monitored my resources during the timeouts (via ssh) and nothing spikes at all. My CPU is always under 7%, disk i/o is always low, ram usage, etc.

I'm currently testing with a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server and Nginx 1.14 with all settings default. No software firewall enabled. I'm ONLY using nginx, no php or database or anything else. Using the default static HTML file. I've reformatted my server 4-5 times and tried different distros and nginx versions.

My service is ATT Fiber. I went into my router settings and tried disabling the ip filter, disabled ipv6, disabled all extra/advanced options in the firewall. I looked through the routers logs, where it shows dropped packets, but I don't see any of my requests there.

I enabled the options to show timings in my nginx access.log but it's of no use as far as I can tell. I'll post it just in case though.

```
192.168.1.254 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.254 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.254 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.105 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.105 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.105 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.105 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.105 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.105 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.105 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.105 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.105 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.254 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
192.168.1.254 - - [20/Jun/2019:02:30:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"request_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time="-" upstream_header_time="-" upstream_response_time="-"
```

The first 3 requests that show 192.168.1.254 were made in chrome via my public ip and went through my router. After the 3rd request, the page wasn't responding anymore and I switched to local ip. It was working fine via local ip, even though at the same time it wasn't responding to my public requests until much later. All the timings just show 0 and - so it doesn't seem to help diagnose things.

**Edit:**

Yes, I have a client/server on the same network. I have a computer that's set up as a web server. Recently, pages stop loading at random though. This only happens when my server is accessed through the external IP or through a domain that points to my external ip. I'm testing the server right now using my desktop, which is hooked into the same router/internet service.

I don't understand exactly how testing from the same network works. But, everything was working properly in the past.. I think the problems started when I switched internet providers and modem/router etc.

I just pinged my external ip address while also reproducing the problem with my web server but the issue didn't affect the packet test at all. I'll try out wireshark.. but I'm not familiar with it so it may take some time.

```
    Packets: Sent = 400, Received = 400, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: (1) Please clarify: it sounds like you have a client and a server on the same local network segment, but you’re communicating between them (or trying to) using the external, publically-visible IP address.  Is that right?  (2) Do you understand how that is working?  Please explain your understanding.  (3) Can you do other forms of communication between these two machines using the public IP? At the very least, you should be able to ping.  What happens if you do that while the http traffic is lagging?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (4) Have you tried using something like Wireshark to see what packets are arriving where, when, and identifying the bottleneck? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Do you have the same issue when using IPv6? You mention that you switched routers; that's a significant change, as the router is very involved in the IPv4 LAN→publicIP→LAN path, i.e. "NAT reflection", and some are not as good at it as others.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot to both of you. I looked into NAT reflection and I'm pretty sure that is actually the issue I'm having. I tested again on my phone with the external ip and had no connection issue. I also tested with ipv6 on the computer within the servers network and had no issue. So it seems the connection problem is only happening with the public ipv4 ip on the internal network as you both suspected. I guess my new router can't handle this "NAT reflection" loopback deal.

Comment: If you could put it in a reply I'll accept the answer. If you don't get around to it then I can reply myself in case it's of help to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so thanks to Scott and grawity I looked up "Nat reflection" / "loopback" / "hairpinning" and I can see this was the problem. I know for anyone experienced with networking it was obvious. But, for those who run into the same issue with nginx here's a few possible workarounds...

**Note that if you're using WordPress only the first option can potentially work.**

- Ideally, you can set up nginx to listen on both IPv6 and IPv4, and then point your domain to the IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. Just make sure your browser is updated so it prioritizes IPv6. This could fix the problem if your router handles IPv6 better in this situation.. and it'll also be a nice little upgrade. However, this didn't end up working for me because I had the same loopback issue via external IPv6 address. It would fallback to IPv4 while IPv6 was not responding so it was harder to notice.. but the problem remained.
- Setup Nginx to listen to multiple domains and set one of them to your local IP(for you to use). You can either use an actual domain/subdomain or just edit your hosts file with a local domain to point to your local IP.
- Use local IP directly if it's an option.. but it'll only work for a single website, because it'll need to be set as your default_server in nginx config.

Sadly, you can't use multiple domain names for WP, and you can't directly access via IP. I have a couple of WP sites and a couple of other types of sites as well. I currently have **no workaround for my WordPress websites** since my router can't handle IPv6 or IPv4 loopbacks and WP only works via the domain set to external IP's.